# (Laravel) Intervention image cache not working on live server

Tags: php, image, caching, laravel-5, intervention

I build an application using Laravel 5. The image cache by intervention/image was worked on local. But, on live/real server the picture not displaying.

Here's the error code:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1 NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 901:

in Application.php line 901
at Application->abort('404', '', array()) in helpers.php line 21
at abort('404') in ImageCacheController.php line 118
at ImageCacheController->getImagePath('483a2f55-b0c5-366b-a00c-2c84e01f16c3.jpg') in ImageCacheController.php line 41
at ImageCacheController->getImage('blog', '483a2f55-b0c5-366b-a00c-2c84e01f16c3.jpg') in ImageCacheController.php line 27
at ImageCacheController->getResponse('blog', '483a2f55-b0c5-366b-a00c-2c84e01f16c3.jpg')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ImageCacheController), 'getResponse'), array('template' => 'blog', 'filename' => '483a2f55-b0c5-366b-a00c-2c84e01f16c3.jpg')) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('getResponse', array('template' => 'blog', 'filename' => '483a2f55-b0c5-366b-a00c-2c84e01f16c3.jpg')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ImageCacheController), object(Route), 'getResponse') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ImageCacheController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getResponse') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'Intervention\Image\ImageCacheController', 'getResponse') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 701
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

I'm using shared hostind (free) on idhostinger to try my app. Please give me your solution or experience to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

**config/image.php**

```
public_path('images/article')
```

change to

```
$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . '/images/article'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check server image driver (in php_info gd or imagick)
And check laravel image config. (config/image.php)

Intervention Image supports "GD Library" and "Imagick" to process images
internally. You may choose one of them according to your PHP
configuration. By default PHP's "GD Library" implementation is used.
Supported: "gd", "imagick"